# mysql db user host

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

```
 Access denied for user 'root'@'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' (using password: YES)
```

even though I have an entry in mysql.user table that has host as % and user as root.

I did grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%';

Comment: it says "using password: YES". Did you also set a password ? If not, try without giving any password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to see how you are trying to connect to the server to give you additional information.  It is possible that the call to the client (or whatever you are using) is munged in some way.